# UNIX_TIMESTAMP outputting NULL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

I've got a table setup which has populated data.  In column "date", I have dates in the following format:

> yyyymmdd i.e. 20131110

I have created a new field and called it newdate with the text format.

Then, I open up the SQL window and put the following in

```
UPDATE wl_daily
SET
   newdate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)
```

For some reason, it is running correctly, however it only outputs NULL to all the rows.  Also, the column name is blank for some reason

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While John Cronde's answer is correct - it doesnt help your situtation

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y%m%d'))
```

will do the conversion for example

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('20131111', '%Y%m%d'))
```

returns

```
unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE('20131111', '%Y%m%d'))  
---------------------------------------------------
                                         1384128000
```

You should only use this to convert your columns to the date specific columns. Converting each time you need a number will add load and slow down the query if used in production

Comment: I tried the following: _UPDATE wl_daily SET newdate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y%m%d'))_ however once again returned NULL

Comment: what is `date` should be the column containing the text ? quote it with backticks because date is a reserved word

Comment: date is the existing information, ie 20131110 and newdate will be the the timestamp version of date.  I've just added backticks and still have the same issue.

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle or try the select statement above ?

Comment: select statement about returned 1384128000

Comment: There must be a problem with the date in there, is there spaces etc after it ?

Comment: Nope.  Exact copy of a date field (20130701) - no spaces.  Although when browsing the table it gives me the message: _Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 70,880 total, Query took 0.4130 sec) [date: [BLOB - 8 B] - [BLOB - 8 B]]_  Not sure what the BLOB part is about..

Comment: How strange.  I moved the column into a different position in the table, ran the exact same query and it worked..

Answer (score 2):

That's because your field in a string and you're trying to add timestamp to it which *is not* a string. You need to use a [valid datetime field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) like `timestamp` for this to work.

Advice: don't store dates and times as strings. Store them in their [native format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html). It makes working with dates and times *much* easier.

Comment: So I've set the date field to "date" however I still seem to be getting NULL in the newdate field. Any suggestions on what the 2 fields should be?